# document.querySelector not working on dynamic content

Tags: javascript, html, browser, queryselector, browser-console

Why when I'm using `document.querySelector` on a dynamic HTML element, it won't give me the current dynamically set data? Is there a way to get the current data?

#### Example:

If I go to this [stripe page with dynamic html](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/bank-debit-card-payouts#supported-settlement), and I copy the JS path of this element:

[image]
When I press paste and run the code in the console I get:

```js
document.querySelector("#Full > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)")

returns-> <td>EUR</td>
```

But I would expect to get:

```js
returns-> <td>USD</td>
```

I noticed that no matter what country I pick for **Viewing support settlement currencies for** which sets the dynamic HTML, the document query selector always returns the result as if that tab was on the first country in the list, **Austria**.

Comment: `.querySelector()` finds a matching element at the time that you call it. As long as you keep that element in the DOM, you can refer to it and access its properties. It does not work with elements that are created after you call it.

Comment: Also, please do not include pictures of your code. Always include the relevant code itself in your questions.

Comment: Because all the the data is there. It is hidden. So the selector matches the first one and returns it.

Comment: There are multiple `elements` that hold the `id` attributes, so `querySelector` returns the first occurrence.

Comment: 39 elements with the same id :)

Comment: use something like this with coutry id form parent `document.querySelector('#US #Full table tbody tr td:first-child').textContent;`

Comment: @ScottMarcus I didn't include pictures of my code. The code is copied and pasted. The only picture included is a picture of the stripe site to show which element I clicked on.

Comment: You've include 2 lines of code. We expect that you will include ALL the relevant code so that we can replicate your issue and provide a working answer.  Also, you did provide a picture of your HTML, rather than all the HTML as code.

Comment: @ScottMarcus The two lines of code is ALL the code. The picture is not of my HTML- that is of the Stripe's public website- the site I was parsing. I did not share their code as I do not have it. I instead shared a link to the page so others can replicate my problem by parsing the site as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

querySelector returns the first item it finds that match. If you look at the source code the "dynamic" code is it just shows and hides a section. Each section has a table.

So what do they use to show it `selected`, but it is done on multiple levels. To get to the element that you are seeing as #Full, it would be

```
document.querySelector(".tabs-tab.selected .tabs-tab.selected")
```

The full selector would be

```
document.querySelector('.tabs-tab.selected .tabs-tab.selected > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(1)')
```

Comment: I think single time `.tabs-tab.selected` also works well, no need to add two times. https://prnt.sc/xq02ck

Comment: @Onkar it works when you add the `> table ....` I rather just be safe

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to get data from that that path than you can use following code.
just find the full xpath of website element using developer tools from chrome or firefox. Than replace fullXpath with your Fullxpath.

Note: I notice That normal xpath also does not work, so thats why use full xpath instead of xpath.

```
 let fullXpath =  "/html/body/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/article/section[2]/div/div/div[34]/div/div/div[1]/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]";
    document.evaluate(fullXpath, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue.innerHTML;
```

This will give you the desire result you are looking.